# Пример с копированием строки на Си: почему мы делаем это через массив?

Tags: c++, c

В коде реализован аналог функции strcpy():

```
char *s = get_string("s: "); // Запрашивает строку
char *t = malloc(strlen(s) + 1);

for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n + 1; i++)
{
   t[i] = s[i];
}

t[0] = topper(y[0]);

printf("%s\n", s);
printf("%s\n", t);
```

Объясните пожалуйста, если *t и *s являются указателями которые хранят адрес первого символа строки, почему далее мы работаем с ними как с массивами? (t[i] = s[i])

Более того, здесь мы обращаемся к их содержимому напрямую, не используя оператор доступа "*" копируя каждый символ из одной строки в другую.

Что происходит в памяти при объявлении char указателя и присваивании ему строкового значения?

Comment: я могу ошибаться лет 15 на С не писал, но как мне кажется вот такая запись `t[i]` будет делать то ж самое, что такая `*(t+i)`

Comment: Да действительно, можно как через звёздочку так и через кв-скобки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще-то наоборот, при `t[i] = s[i]` мы работаем с массивами, как с указателями (если бы это были массивы). Встроенный `operator []` возвращает элемент применяя смещение к указателю и разыменовывая результат, эквивалентно `*(t + i) = *(s + i)`.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь все становится логичным :)